# How to redirect to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/' instead of 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/profile/'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to edit user profiles. The user edits a form on profile.html and when they submit it, they should be redirected back to profile.html (the same page). Even though I changed my LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, I'm still redirecting to accounts/login (the default).

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":
        signupform = SignUpForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if signupform.is_valid():
              signupform.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', "context stuff here")
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile')
```

How can I successfully redirect to profile.html?

Answer (score 1):

Try this replacing **APPNAME** with your app's name (same as the app name you declared in `INSTALLED APPS` section in `settings.py`) in the code below

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('APPNAME:profile'))`

and don't forget to import at the top of your page

`from django.urls import reverse`

Comment: Doing return HttpResponseRedirect("/") redirects me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", which is the login screen. It's weird because doing this seems to automatically log the user out when they click the submit form button. I also tried HttpResponseRedirect("") and the redirect page is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/" like I want, but I'm getting a blank white screen (even though the url seems correct?)

Answer (score 0):

You use `@login_required` decorator but you are not logged in. So that it redirects you to the login page. If you login then it redirect to `/profile`.

Comment: But if the user is on the edit profile page, they're already logged in. Then, they edit their profile so when they submit the form they should still be logged in, I believe? Could you elaborate on where exactly I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: first check in your profile function `user = request.user`. Is user have a value, test it?

Comment: Yea, user has the right value (it prints out the username of the logged in user)

Comment: Yeah, the profile data is successfully updated, just the url doesn't work!

Comment: try this `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))` insteed of this `return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
@login_required
#...
   if signupform.is_valid():
          signupform.save()
          return redirect('profile') # or 'app_name:profile' if you have app_name before your urlpatterns.
```

Your login_required will redirect you to settings.LOGIN_URL

So in your settings add `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'`

If the user is logged in the views will work perfectly.

Addition to that, (template level)
You can also check authentication in html,

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
#html
{% else %}
show something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This redirects me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/profile/"... :/

Comment: So what is your profile view? Can you share the URL you want to redirect.

Comment: I posted the url (urls.py) in my submission. Basically, the user is on profile.html and after they edit their profile I want to redirect them to the same page they are on (the profile page). This url is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/". Sorry, I'm kind of new to Django so if I have any misconceptions about how this works, lmk!

Comment: Edited the answer.